# Ajax comment form error with Fivestar

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, rating

I have a page that loads the comments section via Ajax once the user scrolls down to the comment section via a custom Drupal ajax callback I defined:

Comments are loaded fine, and using a custom module I'm able to delete, edit, reply and preview comments via Ajax successfully.

The Comment form is loaded via Ajax as well, using this function:

http://paste2.org/p/2757034

**Now, here's the problem.**

[image: Comment form]

When the comment form isn't a reply to another comment, if I preview the comment and then save, I get this error:

> The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page.

Now, here is the code that's generating the form after it's previewed:

http://paste2.org/p/2757036

I tried drupal_rebuild_form() instead of drupal_build_form, but I had no success.
I searched a lot for a workaround but couldn't find one.

**EDIT:**
It appears that **Fivestar** is causing the problem. After disabling Fivestar, the form is submitted successfully. However I can't remove fivestar from this page.

Here's what's in $form_state when I click in the preview button:

[image: Fivestar screwing up the form]

Comment: try to set $form['no_cache'] = TRUE. it's quick and dirty

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but when I tried that, clicking the save button started an ajax request but didn't return anything. I don't think it's possible to use no_cache for Ajax forms.

Comment: Fivestar widget itself is an Ajax form. Can you try it with autosubmit set to false ? See the fivestar form. There gotta be be some auto_submit or something set to TRUE. 
This will of course remove the "Ajax-ness" for now but you can at least see if the problem is the form-inside-form or Fivestar's Ajax. 
Fivestar module does not use standard #ajax of Form API.

Comment: I am sure you would have looked at this but just in case. there is an ajax comments module. http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments you might get some pointers there as well.

Comment: Ayesh K, I tried form_alter'ing the fivestar comment form and I've set $form['vote']['#auto_submit'] = FALSE; and $form['vote']['#settings']['autosubmit'] = FALSE;. But the problem persists.

Comment: Mohammed, yeah, I searched that module's issue queue a lot

Comment: could you send me the module itself so that I can test it ou in my system..

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help. I fixed my problem with this patch: http://drupal.org/node/1370526#comment-5367970

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a really annoying Fivestar bug:

http://drupal.org/node/1370526#comment-5367970

The problem is now fixed.

Comment: Nice catch Fidelix!